# PHP image upload script (need to add reduce size, compress and rotate with EXIF data)

Tags: php, android, html, ios, exif

I am a newbie to programming, and this is my first exposure to PHP. I am building a mobile web app where users can upload pictures to the site while at the social event.
I used the PHP script from W3schools (don't hate me please, but it works for my limited knowledge).
Because it is a mobile app I need to add extra functionality but cannot figure out how with the multitude of scripts and my lack of knowledge.
Before the image is uploaded in the script, I would like first do the following.

1) Reduce the dimension to 500px wide and 'auto' the height to retain picture ratio.

2) Compress the file so it is more appropriately filesized for resolution on mobile devices (it will never be printed) and to speed up the upload over cell network.

3) Ensure that the display is correct by way of EXIF data. Right now, iOS, Android and Windows all display portrait and landscape images differently,...I need consistency

Here is my code,...I have remarked where I think it should go but I am not entirely sure.
This code comes up in a pop-up div tag over the page that displays the images.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_dir = $target_dir . basename( $_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"]);
$target_dir1 = $target_dir . basename( $_FILES["uploadFile"]["tmp_name"]);
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["uploadFile"]["tmp_name"]; 
$uploadOk=1;

// Check if Upload is done without file.
if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button")';
    echo '</script>';
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'window.history.back()';
    echo '</script>';
    }

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_dir . $_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"])) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
   $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($uploadFile_size > 500000) {
  echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
   $uploadOk = 0;
}

//Check no php files
if ($uploadFile_type == "text/php") {
    echo "Sorry, no PHP files allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk==0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else { 

        //Reduce file to 500px wide
        //Compress file
        //Rotate file with EXIF data to properly display.

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadFile"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir1)) {
       echo header( 'Location: gallery.php' ) ;

    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks for any help and as mentioned this is my first exposure to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free utility called SimpleImage.php, available at http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/php-image-resizing.php that will handle resizing and compression and might be a good starting point. There are great examples on their page on how to use it, below is an example of how I use it to resize uploaded images to a certain width:

```
require_once("SimpleImage.php");

function createThumbnail($cat_code) {
    // Check for full size product image
    $fname = $this->getImageFilename($cat_code);
    if($fname === "") {
        echo "<b>createThumbnail: No image file found for " . $cat_code . "!</b><br>"; 
        return false;
    }
    $thumb = "images/t/" . $cat_code . ".100.jpg";
    if($fname !== "") {
        $image = new SimpleImage();
        $image->load($fname);
        $image->resizeToWidth(100);
        $image->save($thumb);
    }
    return true;
}

function process_upload($file, $cat_code, $format, $price=NULL) {
    $imageFileExtensions = array('jpg', 'gif', 'png');
    $target_path = "uploads/";
    $target_path1 = $target_path . basename($file['name']);
    $path_info1 = pathinfo($target_path1);
    $ext = $path_info1['extension'];
    if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target_path1)) {
        if(rename($target_path1, $main_path1)) {
            echo "File ". $file['name'] . " verified and uploaded.<br>";
            //Create thumbnail if this is an image file
            if(in_array($ext, $imageFileExtensions))
                $createThumbnail($cat_code);
        } else {
            echo "<b>ERROR renaming " . $file['name'] . "</b><br>"; 
        }
    }
    else
        echo "<b>move_uploaded_file(" . $file['tmp_name'] . ", $target_path1) failed</b><br>\n";
}
```

To do a rotate just add another function to the SimpleImage class that uses `imagerotate()`, for example the following:

```
function rotate($angle, $bgd_color, $ignore_transparent=0) {
    imagerotate($this->image, $angle, $bgd_color, $ignore_transparent);
}
```

The php.net page for [imagerotate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php) has more details on the function parameters.

To work with EXIF data, I use another free utility called PelJpeg.php, available at http://lsolesen.github.io/pel/.  There are many examples on how to use this if you google PelJpeg.php.  It can get kind of complicated, because as you mention, every platform handles images and meta data a little differently, so you have to do a lot of testing to see what things are handled the same on various platforms, what things are different, and how to bridge across those gaps.

Comment: Thanks @David G, I will look at this stuff, although it may be beyond my "syntax" and programming knowledge of PHP.

Comment: Your SimpleImage.php suggestion resolved the sizing and compression issue,...so thank you.  But I am struggling to apply the rotation resolution,...just cannot get it to work.  I am very junior in knowledge for programming and cannot figure it out.

Comment: @DarrenE I added an example above on how to add the rotate function, should be super easy.

Comment: Thanks @David G, I tried and it doesn't work,...but I know why.  I looked at the EXIF data from a picture uploaded from an iPhone and it is very limited.  It is only uploading the "JPEG Makernote" portion and not the "EXIF Makernote" details.  No of these script worked because the "Orientation" detail is not in the upload file.  Back to the drawing board.

Comment: I am wondering when the EXIF data gets stripped.  Is it possible to read the EXIF data while in File Select mode, prior to uploading?  I will test...

Comment: Did some testing and found out that, using the `<input>` tag has some challenges on mobile.  I can see EXIF data BEFORE uploading if I select picture from "Photo Library", but if I select "Take Picture" on the fly it does not.  This is frustrating...